# Use of Outstanding

Tags: word-usage

I saw an ad of a reputable brand which had the following headline: *Start Outstanding*.

[image: BMW Qatar advertisement for the X1 that reads 'Start Outstanding']

Is it a correct use of the word *outstanding*? It sounds wrong but I wonder how it got past the proofing.

Comment: It's hard to say without context. Could you provide a link?

Comment: There was no context. It was the headline. Start Outstanding. And then in the body they mention standing out of the crowd. There is no link, and I cannot upload a pic in here :s

Answer (score 1):

> **Start outstanding**(!)

is an **imperative** to **begin remarkably**. It is **grammatically correct**.

**Outstanding** is a **gerund** modifying **start** (how to start)

It should not be confused with

> Start out standing

which would mean **to begin standing** outside *somewhere*

Comment: Gerunds are nouns and can't modify things.  However, would you say *start* here is being used as a copular verb (e.g. like *Be outstanding* or *It seems outstanding*) and therefore *outstanding* is functioning as a "participial adjective" - a fancy name for an -ing word being used as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Advertising copy should be considered to be – or at least suspected of being – a commercial sort of poetry, where word-play and "poetic license" are used persuasively to seduce the potential buyer.

In this case, "start outstanding" is possibly incorrect.  Now, there *is* a reading in which it is grammatically correct, an unusual sense in which it may be literally read, meaning "be remarkably good from the beginning".  It's not very idiomatic, and as a stand-alone phrase a little weird.  But if you said, "Start outstanding, but end mind-blowing", it would be perfectly clear to an English speaker that you meant "be very good at the beginning, and only get better from there".

But chances are the ad copy used the phrase because of its attention-arresting ambiguity and incongruity.  It suggests the ideas, ungrammatically, "begin to be outstanding" (in the sense of "very good") and "begin to stand out" (in the sense of "distinguished from others").  It invokes a host of compound "out" verbs – outman, outgun, outmaneuver, outfight, outthink, outfox, etc – all of which mean to dominate or triumph in contest.  The grammatical position of "outstanding" in the phrase makes the reader anticipate a verb there, and that "-ing" ending sure sounds like a verb; but "outstanding" is an adjective, and it forces the reader to re-parse the whole phrase – or the reader is made to consider "outstand" as a (made up) verb, constructed in parallel to those other out- verbs.  So it, by means of poetic license, suggests to the potential customer that adopting the product so touted will make them dominate their competition.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least two possible interpretations which might have been intended by the writers, but in neither case do I think it is strictly grammatically correct.

My first thought is to interpret *outstanding* as a **gerund**. In that case the meaning would be the same as something like

> start excelling

That is, you weren't outstanding before, but you will now start to be (by using our product). However, this doesn't quite work grammatically, because *outstand* does not exist as a verb (or at least, not with the meaning implied by *outstanding*), so we can't really create a gerund in this way.

My second thought is that *outstanding* is actually serving as an **adverb**. But in this case the proper form should have been

> start outstandingly

rather than the adjectival form, *outstanding*.

And now I've just seen your comment about the body text referring to "standing out from the crowd", which suggests a third interpretation (again, *outstanding* acts as a **gerund**):

> start standing out

which is a slightly over-literal (but not necessarily incorrect) meaning for *outstanding*.

Most likely the intent was that we should imply all of these meanings, and more: the grammatical imprecision introduces ambiguity, which was almost certainly the writers' desired effect. It is also quite common in advertising for precise grammar to be neglected in the interests of 'snappy' expression: "start outstanding" sounds a lot sharper than "start outstandingly", for example.